# How to change the font size of title property of a hubtile

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am using the hubtile control from the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit
the xaml code for it is

```
<toolkit:HubTile x:Name="hub" Margin="12,12,0,0"                                             
                         Title="{Binding Title}"                        
                         Message="{Binding Message}"
                         Source="{Binding Image}"
                         GroupTag="BindingHubTile" Tap="HubTile_Tap_1">
                                </toolkit:HubTile>
```

how to change the font size of the title property so that the whole title fits in?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
One way is find HubTile class and change default font size.

Answer (score 0):

Download "[Auto Scaling TextBlock for Silverlight](http://edventuro.us/2010/03/an-auto-scaling-textblock-for-silverlight/)" class and include it in your project.

Modify the ControlTemplate of the HubTile control to use the AutoScalingTextBlock instead of just TextBlock for title.