# How to customize text in Windows phone 8 hubtile control

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a possibility to make sure that the text from the title or the message from a hubtile
will fit in the cell (similar to TextWrapping). I have titles and messages with more than one
word and I can't find a way to display them property.

Comment: First of all this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293374/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-title-property-of-a-hubtile

Answer (score 0):

Also plese read this article:http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HubTile_in_Windows_Phone. You will find there examples of HubTiles with Titles and Messages, which have a several words